# Create csv file from sharepoint list

Tags: list, sharepoint

How can I create a csv file from sharepoint list in power automate?
I wanna get just item created or modified in sharepoint list. But I’m using ‘’get item’’ for get just item that is modified.

Thanks.

I am trying use select after get item and before create csv table.

But select requires ‘from’ and I dont know why is not getting from ‘get item ‘

Answer (score 0):

See: https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/Create-CSV-using-sharepoint-list/td-p/1324857

- `Get Items` to get items from SharePoint.
- `Select` to pick what you want from these items. Use the result of `Get Items` for `From`.
- `Create CSV Table` to make a table from the `Select` result.
- `Create File` to make a CSV file from the `Create CSV Table` result.

There's more information and screenshots in the link above, please try and let me know if this helps.